# Mod function odd even

Tags: javascript

I need to insert a class attribute of "odd" or "even" for each paragraph in the HTML displaying using the modulo and ternary operator.
I extracted the paragraph element, but I am unsure of how to insert the class and word the code within the ternary operator. I know my code is pretty terrible, but any tips or suggestions would be wonderful.

```
function oddEven()
{
    var parArray= document.getElementsByTagName("p");

    for(var i=0; i<parArray.length; i++)
    {
        (parArray % 2== 0)? parArray=="even" : parArray=="odd"; 
    }
    //end of oddEven()    
}
```

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function oddEven() {
    var i, elements = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    for(i = 0; i < elements.length; i += 1) {
       elements[i].className = i % 2 === 0 ? "even" : "odd";
    }
}
```

You can also do it directly with CSS without any JavaScript:

```
p:nth-child(even) {
    background: #00ff00;
}
p:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

This only works if the `p`s share a common parent though.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for your help! That was a blazing fast response as well.

Answer (score 3):

That's easily done with CSS, but if you want to learn JS, here's your example with minimal modifications:

```
function oddEven() {
  var parArray = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

  for (var i = 0; i < parArray.length; i++) {
    parArray[i].classList.add((i % 2 == 0) ? "even" : "odd");
  }
  //end of oddEven()    
}
```

So, for parity, you need to check the value of `i`, not the `parArray`, and to assign a class name, I used `classList`, but you can use `className`, etc...

---

See it live here:

```js
function oddEven() {
  var parArray = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

  for (var i = 0; i < parArray.length; i++) {
    parArray[i].classList.add((i % 2 == 0) ? "even" : "odd");
  }
  //end of oddEven()    
}

oddEven();
```

```css
.odd {color: blue}
.even {color: green}
```

```html
<p>paragraph</p>
<p>paragraph</p>
<p>paragraph</p>
<p>paragraph</p>
<p>paragraph</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function no have chances to work. You are selecting p elements properly, but getElementsByTagName returns an Array of p elements so by parArray=="even" you are trying to compare Array of objects with String. Look at my code below and compare with yours.

I recomend you reading [Change an element's class with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript)

```
    function oddEven()
    {
        var parArray = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
        var pElement;
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < parArray.length; i++)
        {
            pElement = parArray[i];
            pElement.className += (i % 2) ? 'odd' : 'even';
        }
    }
```